# How to query with a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const mappings = {
  greeting: {
    'en': [
      'Hello',
      'Hi',
      'Hey'
    ],
    'it': [
      'Ciao',
      'Buongiorno',
      'Buonasera'
    ]
  }
}
```

Based on the language in the query, I would like to pick that language up.
So I tried `const language = req.query.language` which can be `it` or `en`. But when I try to return Hello or Ciao `mappings.greeting.language[0]` it does not return anything, because it doesn't pick up the variable `language`.

How can I pass the variable in my query?

Comment: try this `mappings.greeting[language][0]` instead of this `mappings.greeting.language[0]`. Because there is no field with this name in your  `mappings` array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `language` is a variable, instead of dot notation (`.`) use bracket notation (`[]`) which allows property names as variables:

```
mappings.greeting[language][0]
```

```js
const mappings = {
  greeting: {
    'en': [
      'Hello',
      'Hi',
      'Hey'
    ],
    'it': [
      'Ciao',
      'Buongiorno',
      'Buonasera'
    ]
  }
}
let language = 'en'
console.log(mappings.greeting[language][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this code :

```
const language='en';
const mappings = {
  greeting: {
    'en': [
      'Hello',
      'Hi',
      'Hey'
    ],
    'it': [
      'Ciao',
      'Buongiorno',
      'Buonasera'
    ]
  }
};
console.log(mappings.greeting[language][0])
```